# Visual Studio: Why does a "clean-up" solve the issue in my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

this is an odd one. It is about this bits of code:

```
if(intInstanz == 1 && boolTutorialWasAlreadyVisible == false)
{ 
    new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this) // if this crashes, we need clean rebuild
        .Title(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Tutorial1))
        .TitleStyle(0, (int)GravityFlags.Bottom | (int)GravityFlags.Center)
        .FocusOn(btnBackground)
        .Build()
        .Show();

    boolTutorialWasAlreadyVisible = true;
}
```

This `FancyShowCaseView` is used to be a tutorial towards an app. But sometimes - out of the blue - it crashes saying `"trying to invoke method on a null object"`.

I have tried it all. Changed every variable around to eventually NOT get it to work. However - cleaning up and rebuilding the project (via a right-click on the solution) fixed this problem immediately.

But this concerns me: What if we are to launch our app soon and this issue occurs on our users phones who of course do not have the option to clean and rebuild the app? Or is this something that MUST be related to the debug mode the app is currently in? How come that this issue is solved without changing a single line of code. But then, after a random while it reappears only to be solved yet again by cleaning the project?

I hope I have made my issue clear. What exacly does the clean up click do and will the be a problem on the final, released, version of the app?

Thank you!

---

Now that I coded a little bit around somewhere completely else, I got the same issue yet again. Cleaning the solution once more did the trick - however I was able to capture the exact message VS gave me:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Are you sure it's the problem of cleaning and rebuilding, and not only restarting your application and releasing resources so new memory could be allocated?

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes I am sure. I have done everything else but it needed to be cleaned...

Comment: Such is the hazard of "fluent style".  If it crashes like this you just have no idea which of these methods returned null.  Can't ask for help with it either.